# how to wrap 2 html element or more with loop in vuejs

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, vue.js

i want wrap 2 html element

This is my code in `vuejs`

```
<tr>
    <th v-for="(item9,index) in product_all" :key="item9.id"><center>Qty</center></th>
    <th v-for="(item99,index) in product_all" :key="item99.id"><center>Amount</center></th>
</tr>
```

this is what i want (in laravel blade)

```
<tr>

    @foreach($dataProduct['byShowTanggal'] as $row)

        <th>Qty</th>

        <th>Amount</th>

    @endforeach
</tr>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can hang the `v-for` off a `<template>` element.

```html
<tr>
  <template v-for="item in product_all">
    <th :key="item.id + 'Qty'"><center>Qty</center></th>
    <th :key="item.id + 'Amount'"><center>Amount</center></th>
  </template>
</tr>
```

`<template>` is a special element that won't create a corresponding DOM node.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt

I've also tweaked the keys for your elements to ensure they are different for the two elements.